# Plugin on send message in email entity not executing when email is sent by workflow in dynamics crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a scenario where I have to integrate CRM with Sendgrid email system. I need to add information to email header of outgoing email for tracking.

I decided to bypass email router and directly send email via sendgrid API using Plugin registered on SEND message of EMAIL entity. Plugin works fine when a user sends an email from CRM UI and a email is delivered to intended recipient via Sendgrid API call.

The issue is plugin is not invoked if the email is being sent as a part of a workflow process, custom code activity or custom Plugin. I have tried attaching debugger while the execution of workflow but the pointer does not intercept the code.

Did anyone else faced anything like this?

Comment: Hello,

Please provide a screenshot of workflow, code of custom workflow activity or plugin that used to send an email.

Comment: Hi Andrii,

There is no specific workflow that is having the issue. any email that is not sent through CRM UI and is sent through a workflow, Plugin is not hitting the POST- OPERATION plugin registered on SEND message in EMAIL entity. The Plugin is hit by the email sent by CRM Web UI by clicking the SEND button.

This is a strange behavior. I do not understand why is the plugin is working for email send through WEB UI and not for email sent through Plugin or Workflow.

Comment: Plugin Code-

<Code>

Comment: Edit initial post with code. Code is not visible in comments.

Comment: Hi Manu! Having the same problem. Where you able to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Removing code below allowed plugin to run on

```
//if (context.Depth > 1) return;
```

Check if you are returning on context.Depth and remove or increase the Depth number.